# how do you change a single char in a 2D array (C)

Tags: c

How can I change a single character in a 2D array in C? I have tried but can't get it to compile...

`char *words[50][20];`

`words[0][0] = "hello";`

Now how can I change the 'h' to 'j' to make it "jello"?

Comment: To make sure that your program is compilable, following the C++ documentation carefully. Especially regarding the const-ness of string literal.

Comment: @user202729, this is C not C++

Comment: @smac89 ... well then, C documentation.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Make sure you understand `char *words[50][20];` creates a 2D array of pointers to `char` (`1000` pointers to be exact) not not a 2D array of 50 20-character arrays. It is likely the latter is what you intended (or you may be doing something really creative that just escapes me at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try that because modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. Reasonable thing is to do this,

```
const char *p = "Hello";
words[0][0]=malloc(strlen(p)+1);
if(words[0][0]==NULL){
  perror("malloc");
  exit(1);
}
memcpy(words[0][0],p,strlen(p)+1);
```

Remember that you have declared a 2d array of `char*` - that's why allocated memory first using `malloc` and then copied the string literal. All this can be done with POSIX specified `strdup`

```
words[0][0]=strdup("Hello");
```

In C standard it is explicitly mentioned that modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. You should not use the code you have written for the very reason stated above.

After doing the changes you can make changes like `words[0][0][0]='j'` and that would be the correct code.

Also reconsider your design carefully. We seldom need 2d array of `char*` do you need it here? If not try to make design simpler with smaller constructs.

```
char *words[50];
```

And now you can make each pointer point to words which has different number of letters in it. The code would be quite similar to the earlier case - but instead of using `words[0][0]` you would use `words[0]`, something like

```
words[0]=malloc(strlen(p)+1);
...
```

Or  `words[0]=strdup("Hello");`.

The standard section which talks about string literal is given below, from [6.4.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7) (note the array means the string literal)

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. *If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined*.

Comment: awesome thx much appreciated, I noticed that it worked fine with a 1D array which is why I tried it with 2D array, for instance if I said: